# Eclipse Python Console Outputs Nothing

Tags: python, eclipse

I tried running the code below but my console outputs nothing after running this program, i have created similar table using sqlite3 on same IDE, but do not understand why this outputs nothing

```
import sqlite3

def connect():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Books.db")
    curr = conn.cursor()
    curr.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    title TEXT, author TEXT,year INTEGER, isbn INTEGER)")
    curr.commit()
    curr.close()


def ins(title,author,year,isbn): 
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Books.db")
    curr = conn.cursor()
    curr.execute("INSERT INTO book values(NULL,?,?,?,?)", 
    (title,author,year,isbn))  
    curr.commit()
    curr.close()


def see():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Book.db")
    curr = conn.cursor()
    curr.execute("SELECT * FROM book")  
    rows= curr.fetchall()
    curr.close()
    return rows


    connect()

    ins("The Man", "John Tablet", 1967,9131003)  

    print(see())
```

Comment: If you passed it exactly like that then the last three lines are incorrectly indented (i.e. like this they are part of the `see` function)

Comment: Is it just not printing output of this scipt above? Or in general? I remember PyDev having its console messed up for me once, Had to drop and recreate the interpreter definition in Eclipse/PyDev.

Comment: just this script above @shmee 22, it prints for others

Comment: Then @FlyingTeller might be right about the indentation in his comment. If the indentation in your question reflects what you have in your actual code, you just define three functions, but none gets executed, hence you get no output. Move the last three lines to the same level that your `def` keywords are on.

Comment: Thank you so much @Flying Teller that fixed it